# A single word to describe a young, successful team or organization

Tags: single-word-requests

My kid's youth soccer club (let's call it Team A) is merging with another club (Team B).  I am working on a website banner to announce the merger.

Team A has been around for over 40 years and quite successful for most of those years.  To describe that club in one word I have chosen *Tradition*.

Team B is a young, but also successful team.

I want the banner to be a simple formula:  Team A + Team B = Excellence

Under each team I want the best word to describe that team:

```
Team A      +   Team B
Tradition       [blank]
            =
       EXCELLENCE
```

Help me fill in the [blank].  :)

What would be a good word to describe a young, but successful team/organization?

**Bonus:**  If you can think of a better word than "EXCELLENCE", that'd be great too!

Comment: I'm not too sure how well they'd fit with something like a football team, but a well-established pairing for *commercial products* is ***traditional / innovative***.

Comment: So, I want reemphasize that the younger team is also already successful.   I feel like "aspiring" and "modern" doesn't communicate that.  Maybe we need to iterate on words meaning successful and de-emphasize the youthful nature of the second club.

Comment: enthusiasm or initiative ?

Comment: *spirit* might be a good one.   Sort of implies equal footing, but coming from a point of less organizational momentum toward success.

Comment: Ah, I like spirit.  Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Team B can be ***"Young Blood"*** which the Cambridge Dictionary Online [defines](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/young-blood) as:

> ​"young ​people who have a lot of ​energy and ​ideas"

Comment: Hmm, this made me think of "Rising stars", which isn't terrible, because it insinuates the successful nature of Team B.

Comment: Rising Stars is a good one!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a native speaker but my first thought for B was *aspiring* / *emergent*.

Answer (score 1):

```
Team A      +   Team B
Tradition       Modernity
            =
     A perfect balance
```

Another one with extra tweaks :

```
Team A      +   Team B
Classic         Modern
            =
        A modern classic
```

Answer (score 0):

Tradition + Zeal = Excellence

> **Zeal**
>   : a strong feeling of interest and enthusiasm that makes someone very eager or determined to do something [- M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeal)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *ascendance* or *[ascendancy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ascendancy?a=british)*

> a ​position of ​power, ​strength, or ​success

*Cambridge Dictionaries Online*

And possibly *greatness* as an alternative to *excellence*.